Whence comes the expression ‘’starve a cold, feed a fever?”
What is the origin of the expression "starve a cold, feed a fever"? It is is used as basic (perhaps incorrect) medical advice for common illnesses.

Please provide some information from your own research about the origin of this as described in how to ask a good question in the [help].  If you are asking if it's true, you are not on the right SE, maybe try [medicalsciences.SE].

I found a helpful article with a Google search for the (unpunctuated) expression.

Are you asking whether the saying is true, where the underlying idea came from, or where the specific saying originated? The last of those is on-topic here; the first two aren't.

The Ngram graph for "starve a cold" versus "starve a fever" suggests that you may have the expression backward. If question reviewers are willing restrain themselves from closing this question for a few hours, I would be happy to research the origin of both forms of the expression ("starve a cold, feed a fever, and "starve a fever, feed a cold").

I think this is still a good question, considering the many ways the phrase has been misused, abused and misquoted. Such is part of our strum und drang.

I've always known it as feed a cold and starve a fever, understanding it to mean that you should eat plenty if you have a cold but not if you are feverish. However, there is a suggestion that it means "If you eat well when you have a cold it won't turn into a fever" (before people understood about bacteria and viruses).

Basic research? Scientific American readily provides:<< Maxims typically date back many years, but “feed a cold, starve a fever” may beat them all. This saying has been traced to a 1574 dictionary by John Withals, which noted that “fasting is a great remedy of fever.” The belief is that eating food may help the body generate warmth during a “cold” and that avoiding food may help it cool down when overheated.
But recent medical science says the old saw is wrong. It should be “feed a cold, feed a fever.”>>

I was told by my GP that this was a mis-quotation and the original saying was "Feed a cold, stave a fever"
The meaning therefore was: if you eat well while you have a cold, you will prevent it turning into a fever.  Not sure how reputable the advice is, but since it meant I could 'feed' both a cold and a flu, I kept going with it :)

Related: Should this question . . . be reopened?.

I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for medical advice about a motto that was based on Victorian, or earlier, ignorance.

@SvenYargs and you can expand your result to include feeding colds and fevers

I had heard that the original use was If you starve a cold you will [be] feed [ing] a fever That is you should not starve one with cold symptoms or a fever may come from it. When I find the source I will make it an answer.

I've always heard it as "feed a cold, stave a fever" and associated the saying with the observation that colds make you hungry (and with common cold remedies like chicken soup) whereas fevers often cause you to lose your appetite. Not so much medical advise as an observation of what your body is typically already telling you in those scenarios.

Robert Hendrickson, The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins, fourth edition (2008) has this relevant entry:

feed a cold, starve a fever. The great Greek physician Hippocrates, called the father of medicine, is said to have invented this advice. People have in any case been following his words for centuries, although several doctors have recently claimed that there is no scientific truth to his advice.

C.J. Springell, The Aphorisms of Hippocrates and the Sentences of Celsus: With Explanations and References to the most considerable Writers in Physick and Philosophy, Both Ancient and Modern (1708) doesn't cite any aphorisms that use the proverb-length language, but it does include aphorisms that recommend different diets for patients with different illnesses. Thus, for example:

Aphorism VII. When the disease is very sharp, and is immediately attended with dangerous Symptoms, we must use a most exquisitely slender Diet. But when it is not so, we must use a fuller Diet, and as the Disease declines, we may gradually and proportionably increase the Diet.
Explanation. The more acute the Disease, the more tender the Diet.

On the other hand:

Aphorism IV. A Slender and delicate Diet is in lingering Diseases always dangerous, and in acute Diseases likewise where it is not convenient. And again Diet reduced to extream Slenderness, is as full of Peril, as extream Repletion.
Explanation. The Diet is to be managed according to the Ability of the Patient and the Disease. For one in a violent Fever must take things of but little Nourishment, and one in a lingering or Hecktick Fever cannot be cured except it be with the Assistance of a good nourishing Diet.

And:

Aphorism V. The Sick may offend in a slender Diet, and thereby grow worse. For every Error in this Case, is more dangerous than in a more plentiful Diet. For the same reason a very slender and too precise Diet is somewhat dangerous to sound and healthful Bodies, because they endure the Errors of it with more difficulty. And therefore a thin and exquisite sparing Diet is more dangerous than that which is sometimes too plentiful.
Explanation. A slender Diet is for the most part, but not absolutely hurtful; for there is Moderation in all things. A Patient may confine himself in his Diet, but not starve  himself.

From these strictures and observations, it is not altogether implausible that a shorthand rule of "Starve a fever and feed a cold" might arise from this source—especially among nonprofessionals rephrasing and simplifying what they took to be professional advice.

Early instances of aphorisms suggesting contrasting treatments for colds and fevers
Fred Shapiro, The Yale Book of Quotations (2006) has this entry for a related phrase:

Stuff a cold and starve a fever. Emerald and Baltimore Literary Gazette, 28 Feb. 1829. An earlier form is "nurse a cold, and starve a fever" (James M. Adair, Medical Cautions, for the Consideration of Invalids {1786}). "Feed a cold and starve a fever" is a common modern variant.

I have not been able to find a readable copy of the cited work by James M. Adair—although, interestingly, his byline in Unanswerable Arguments Against the Abolition of the Slave Trade, With a Defence of the Proprietors of the British Sugar Colonies (1790) identifies Adair as "formerly M.D."
However, the same expression appears in a letter dated February 2, 1801, from Horatio Nelson to Lady Hamilton, reprinted in Memoirs of the Life of Vice-admiral Lord Viscount Nelson (1849):

I rejoice to hear you say you are better; only recollect the old nurse's advice: "nurse a cold, starve a fever;" therefore pray be sure and nurse yourself. If I was Sir William you should not get out of bed for a week, nor out of the house for a fortnight. You ought to follow my advice, as you know how exactly I follow yours when I am sick.

It is not clear from a Google Books search, however, that Adair's "nurse a cold" formulation is older than the competing "stuff a cold." From a review of "A serious Address on the dangerous Consequences of neglecting common Coughs and Colds", second edition, in Gentleman's Magazine: And Historical Chronicle (August 1785):

The most acute and dangerous maladies to which the human frame is subject, are generally the consequences of colds, neglected, or improperly treated. The vulgar and absurd proverb "Stuff a cold, and starve a fever," has, where-ever it has obtained, been perhaps more destructive to mankind than the plague itself. The author recommends the following regimen upon the first appearance of a cold: "As soon as it is found to come upon a person, he should immediately lessen the quantity of his food, which should consist of suppings, moderately warm, especially at night, such as small broths, water-gruel, and the like; the solids should be rice, sago, light puddings, fruits, and vegetables; the drink should be barley-water, small beer, apple-water, linseed tea, toast and water, water-gruel sweetened with honey, or any other cooling liquid."

A similarly critical view of the popular saying appears in The Restorer of Health and Physician of Nature (1792):

We cannot here but observe the pernicious effects of spiritous liquors upon the human body, when taken with the intention to cure a cold, and of a common adage, viz. to stuff a cold, and starve an ague. This, so far from relieving these complaints, aggravates them more than any means whatever. Patients trusting to such remedies, are more indebted to the strength of their constitution, than to their good sense and judgement.

On the other hand, from "Extract from the Diary of a Good Protestant," in The Oeconomist, or, Englishman's Magazine (February 1799):

Tuesday.—Caught a violent catarrh at church: determined to feed well at dinner. Sydenham, I think, says in his chapter on gout, "Starve a fever, but stuff a cold." Rather better towards four o'clock. What a charming cod's head! ha'nt seen its fellow; full of sounds, firm, flakey, and well coloured. Colchester oysters, well-flavoured. Hare soup, an excellent diluent. Stewed beef not quite rich enough! Woodcocks to a Turn! N. B. Toast too hard. Finished, God be thanked, a plentiful meal, (hobnobbing the whole time in Madeira) with a red herring and a slice of toasted cheese.

The nineteenth century saw considerable backlash against the old saying. Two writers, in particular, separately proposed a novel explanation of why the saying had been (in their opinion) widely misunderstood. From "On Certain Proverbial and Colloquial Expressions," in Dublin University Magazine: A Literary and Political Journal (February 1853):

"Feed a cold and starve a fever," is a common saying, which, when taken in the literal sense, has led to dangerous mistakes. The correct reading is directly opposite, and means, "If you feed a cold, you will have to starve a fewer."

And from Lewis Bollman, "Address Delivered Before the Laporte County Agricultural Society, October 6th, 1855," reprinted in Fourth Report of the Indiana State Board of Agriculture, Containing the Transactions of the Board for the Years 1854–'55" (1856):

This misapplication of maxims [as in the case of "like produces like"] is a common and often dangerous error. For instance, the Spanish proverb is—"Feed a cold and starve a fever." In that language it is an admonition to beware of feeding a cold, lest a fever follow, which must be starved. But we translate it to mean not a caution, but a command—that is, to cure a cold we we must feed it, and to cure a fever we must starve it.


Early advocacy for 'starve a cold'
The earliest occurrence of "starve a cold" that a Google Books search turns up is from "Curing a Cold" in The London and Paris Observer: Or Weekly Chronicle of News, Science, Literature, and the Fine Arts (May 17, 1829):

—Doctor: No, good woman, I think if you had starved instead of stuffed his cold, he would have been well before now. —Mrs. Pheezer: Goodness ha' mercy on ye, doctor! Starve a cold! why I never heard of such a thing in all my born days. —Doctor: May be not, Mrs. Pheezer, but I assure you it is the right way to manage a cold if you mean to get rid of it. For instance, let the patient take a little tea, coffee, or a glass of water, with a cracker three times a-day—or a little water-gruel, if more convenient or agreeable to the taste. By this management a cold may be ordinarily be cured in two or three days, while, by the stuffing process, it would probably be prolonged as many months, unless death should intervene and put an end to the cold and the patient together. —Mrs. Pheezer: Why doctor, I'm astonished at ye. I used to think you know'd something, but now I'm convinced all your skill an't worth a snap o' my thumb. You needn't come any more, Doctor. {Exit physician.} Starve a cold! Well, of all the strange doctrines I ever heard of, this is the cap sheaf. Among all my sins, I hav'nt got this to answer for. —Mrs. Pheezer pursued her stuffing regimen, her husband's cold became an inflammation of the lungs, and, in a week after, Mrs. Pheezer saw him laid in his grave, consoling herself in the midst of her afflictions, that she had not been guilty of the sin of starving his cold.

From William Dewees, A Practice of Physic: Comprising Most of the Diseases Not Treated of in "Diseases of Females," and "Diseases of Children", volume 1 (1830):

With children, the calomel oftentimes answers an admirable purpose [in treating catarrh], by exciting the stomach to vomiting, whenever there is anything crud eor offensive in it, and it very rarely fails afterwards, to affect the bowels. The belly should be kept open during the course of the acute stage of the disease; but it is seldom necessary to purge briskly. Indeed this is sometimes injurious, especially when there is a tendency to diarrhoea, as sometimes happens when the first stage has been neglected or improperly treated, as but too frequently happens, in conformity to an old, but ill-understood adage; namely, feed a cold, but starve a fever." Unfortunately, this proverb is obeyed literally in too many instances; and this sometimes to the destruction of the patient. The true interpretation of this "old saw," is, that you are to starve a cold, because there is always more or less fever with it.

Dewees's use of the exact wording "feed a cold and starve a fever" is the earliest instance of it that I have found in Google Books searches for the phrase. Nevertheless, he refers to it as being, at the time of his writing, "an old, but ill-understood adage" and an "old saw," and he dedicates most of his answer to arguing against it as sound medical advice.
And from "'Feed a Cold and Starve a Fever': Catching Cold," in American Agriculturalist (Wednesday, December 20, 1854):

The above is one of a class of popular "sayings" which have come to be regarded as truisms, but many of which are founded entirely in error. It would be nearer right to say, starve a cold and starve a fever. We believe there are comparatively few of the common ailings which may not be entirely overcome by attention to diet. Take a cold for example. By improper exposure to inequalities of temperature in the system becomes disarranged, and the different functions of the body are performed imperfectly. The circulation of the blood, especially, is disturbed; the usual secretions do not go on; headache and general dullness throughout the system are experienced, and unless a reaction takes place, local inflammation of the throat, lungs, &c., and a partial or general fever is the result.

George Dern, Diary of George Dern; Or, Juttings of a Year of Middle Life (1864) cites a different wording of the proverb in an entry for November 19, 1858:

Four days confined with cold, which has at length ended in a cough. Remembering the maxim "Stuff a cough and starve a cold," I have dined sumptuously, and ordered some whiskey at a chasse.
My ('Marchioness') maid of all work, Mary (whose real name is Anne) has brought me some abominable liquor.
"Mary," says I, "take this back to where you brought it from; I cannot drink it; it is enough to poison a hog."

A backlash to the backlash against the folk medicine prescription "starve a fever but feed a cold" appears in Edward Smith, Health: A Handbook for Households and Schools (1874):

Should food be discontinued during a cold? This is often decided by the patient himself, for he cannot eat; but to starve a cold, as it is called, is rarely wise. Ordinary but simple food, and that always hot and more than usually fluid, is the proper kind of diet.

Henry Thoreau, A Week on the Concord and Merrimack Rivers (1867) expresses consternation at the warring medical advice:

Since all things are good, men fail at last to distinguish which is the bane and which the antidote. There are sure to be two prescriptions diametrically opposed. Stuff a cold and starve a cold are but two ways. They are the two practices both always in full blast. Yet you must take advice of the one school as if there was no other. In respect to religion and the healing art, all nations are still in a state of barbarism.


Assessment
Whether "feed [or nurse or stuff] a cold, starve a fever [or ague]" originated as a distillation of the advice of Hippocrates (as Robert Hendrickson reports) or as a Spanish proverb (as Lewis Bollman asserts) or is simply a "vulgar and absurd proverb" expressing common ignorance of how to treat colds and fevers properly (as The Gentleman's Magazine argues in 1785), the historical record firmly establishes that the original wording involved feeding colds (more or less aggressively) and starving fevers (more or less severely). The exact wording "feed a cold and starve a fever" appears in print at least as early as 1830.
From an early date (no later than 1785), the physicians commenting on the tended to be quite critical of it. I note, however, that some of these same early critics were enthusiastic proponents of applying leeches to patients beset with fevers or colds, or dosing them with opium (among other recommended regimens) instead—so their hostility to the popular advice should be taken with a grain of something nonaddictive.
In any event, opinions have varied immensely, not just with regard to whether "feed a cold, starve a fever" is good advice but also with regard to what the words mean. Subsequent formulations of the proverbial rule have included "feed a cold and feed a fever," "starve a cold and feed a fever," "starve a cold and starve a fever," and the tried-and-true "listen to your stomach."
Martin Manser, The Facts on File Dictionary of Proverbs (2002) offers this useful summary:

feed a cold and starve a fever You should eat well when you have a cold but fast when you have a fever: "'Forget about feeding a cold and starving a fever,' Dr. Edelman said, adding there is no medical reason for diet changes" (Washington Times, 1997) The proverb is sometimes interpreted as a warning that eating well during a cold will bring on a fever, or if you feed a cold now you will have to starve a fever later. Other conflicting explanations interpret starve as "prevent" or even "die of." The proverb was first recorded in 1832, but fasting has been recommended as a remedy for fever since the 16th century or earlier. Variant of this proverb: stuff a cold and starve a fever.

As I noted earlier in my answer, Hippocrates in his Aphorisms recommends treating "very sharp" diseases with "a most exquisitely slender Diet"—evidently giving C.J. Springell a firm precedent for asserting in 1708 that "one in a violent Fever must take things of but little Nourishment." Beyond that, however, the saying as handed down from 1785 to the present day is so ambiguous and variously worded as to be almost completely unhelpful to anyone with a cold or a fever. So my advice is: ask your doctor whether feeding a cold and starving a fever is right for you.

You may want to include the recent [2014] advice Scientific American (link above) provides. // I was about to CV for lack of reasonable research, but this typically thorough answer is a fine illustration of the diachronics (does that exist?) of a perhaps typical maxim.

You say that 'the saying . . . is . . . variously worded'. Doesn't that amount to acknowleding that there is, in fact, no such thing as the saying that is under discussion here? Your answer, informative as your answers always are, seems to be primarily about the history of the idea that certain kinds of diet are well suited for certain illnesses, and only incidentally about the particular English words and grammatical constructions used to express that idea. And that, as @alphabet suggested within minutes of the question being posted, is outside the scope of this site.

@jsw29: My answer looks two things that are generally off topic at EL&U: a source of the medical advice embodied in the main version of the proverb, and the reasons behind subsequent variations on the main version of the proverb. In my view, both are relevant to an EL&U answer about the expression's origin and evolution. The fact that "feed a cold, starve a fever" shows up in multiple dictionaries of proverbs (including several that I didn't cite in my answer) satisfies me that it is, in fact, a proverb—albeit one whose variations and interpretations are numerous and sometimes contradictory.

@jsw29: Most proverbs/sayings admit at least some variation in wording, and tracing their history often leads through a much broader range of variation of wording, sense, and even language.  None of that detracts from there being a clear, recognisable, well-established proverb here that the question is about, as much as in most such questions.

The saying in English apparently dates back to the 16th century from a dictionary by John Withals:

The saying “feed a cold, starve a fever” dates back to a dictionary published by John Withals in 1574 because of a note that indicated “fasting is a great remedy of fever.”
The belief that has carried through the years is that the body needs food to generate warmth for healing from a cold – while avoiding food helps to cool the body when a fever is present. In the 1500s and 1600s, doctors thought that a fever meant that the metabolism was working in overdrive.


The SA article, slightly disguised?
